# How to detect if a player is wearing a custom set of gear

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map in Minecraft with some custom crafting recipes that yield special items that deal with fighting. I know how to do that just fine, but I also want to add a bonus if one is wearing, say, a full set of "emerald armor." For example, if the player is wearing the full set, they would receive jump boost. **So my question to you is: how do I detect if a player is wearing a specific set of gear?** I know how to detect if a player is wearing a specific item with scoreboard and whatnot, but how do I combine those commands for a full set?

Answer (score 1):

> I know how to detect if a player is wearing a specific item with scoreboard and whatnot, but how do I combine those commands for a full set?

You could either put all of the data tags into one scoreboard objective, like this:

```
/scoreboard players set @a FullEmerald 0
/scoreboard players set @a FullEmerald 1 {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,<Helmet tags>},{Slot:102b,<Chestplate tags>}},{Slot:101b,<Leggings tags>}},{Slot:100b,<Boots tags>}}]}
```

Or, alternatively, set up an objective for each of the specific items, then combine them like:

```
@a[score_HelmetEmerald_min=1,score_ChestplateEmerald_min=1,score_LeggingsEmerald_min=1,score_BootsEmerald_min=1]
```

The second method would also really be better if you've already got objectives for each of the individual armor pieces (e.g: each piece individually has powers).

Comment: Why aren't you using a tag instead?  That's the typical implementation for booleans these days.

Comment: @MBraedley I prefer to still use scoreboard objectives for item-holding/armor-wearing because you can't combine tags as easily (only one `tag=` works in a selector). Tags would also work for the first method though, just depends on what else needs to be done with it.

Comment: Never thought about it that way, thank you. I have now completed what I have decided to call the "Emerald Knight," and it's really fun :)